# May I change rgrass7 location in R script

Tags: r, grass-gis, rgrass7

I'm using Grass-GIS 7.2 in R with `rgrass7`. I would like to use rasters from 2 different location. Is there a way to do that without brutality ?
At this time it works with :

```
library(rgrass7)
# initialization and the use of my first location
initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass72", home = tempdir(), 
          gisDbase = "/home/user/Documents/futurSahel/grassDB/",
          location = "landsat8", mapset = "PERMANENT")

# list of all raster loaded in GRASS
execGRASS("g.list", parameters = list(type = "raster"))

ndvi.landsat <- readRAST("ndvi.rescal",  close_OK=TRUE, drivername="GTiff")

##Using the 2nd location
initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass72", home = tempdir(), 
          gisDbase = "/home/user/Documents/futurSahel/grassDB/",
          location = "spot", mapset = "delaye", override=TRUE)

# list of all raster loaded in GRASS
execGRASS("g.list", parameters = list(type = "raster"))

ndvi.landsat <- readRAST("SPOT6_P_20151113",  close_OK=TRUE, drivername="GTiff")
```

Comment: What have you tried?  A question about how to do something in code should include your code attempt and details of what happens when you try it.  Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: sorry ! It's done : more code.

Comment: I would always project rasters into one LOCATION, and thus avoid the minefield of hard-to-debug problems that might come up with mixed CRS. Just do an execGRASS('r.proj",...)